# How does javascript window.location work?

Tags: javascript, debugging, redirect

I am new to the javascript window.location and I was trying to use it to direct to certain pages when certain phrases are entered into a prompt box. Is the way I did it below correct? For some reason it does not seem to work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function desiredPg() {
    var pgDesired = prompt("What do you want?");
    if (pgDesired == "Log In" || "log in") {
        window.location = "google.com";
    } else if (pgDesired == "Register" || "register") {
        window.location = "apple.com";
    } else {
        alert("Please enter a valid page name. Do not forget to use appropriate spaces and capitalize if necessary");
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body onLoad="desiredPg()">
```

Comment: are you calling the function at all?

Comment: It seems right to me...`window.location` redirects the browser to whatever you tell it to.

Comment: yeah, I call it on body load. I verified that worked before I added the if statement, but I will post the rest just in case

Comment: So when you type your text into the prompt box and click "OK", nothing happens?

Comment: pretty much, it sends me to my webhost's error page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **absolute URLs** if you want to go to another host, so simply prepend `http://` to the string.

Convert the string to lower case so you only have to perform one comparison.

I'd suggest that you use a hash, this cleans up the code a ton and needs only one `if` condition:

```
function desiredPg() {
  var pgDesired = prompt("What do you want?");
  var sites = {'log in': 'http://google.com', 'register':'http://apple.com'};

  if (typeof sites[pgDesired.toLowerCase()] !== 'undefined') {
     window.location = sites[pgDesired.toLowerCase()];
  } else {
     alert("Please enter a valid page name.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set `window.location` to a path like 'apple.com', the path is taken as a *relative* path, means, if you are currently viewing Google, it will search for 'google.com/path'.

Try the absolute path instead, including the protocol..

```
  window.location = "http://apple.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside whether it is a good idea to make users remember page names, there are two problems in the code.

First, you have to evaluate each condition in an if statement separately, so those would be like `pgDesired=="A" || pgDesired=="B"` (though Jacob's solution is more robust)

Second, you need to use the absolutely path as ring0 mentioned. So `window.location = "http://apple.com";`

Comment: yeah, I know that making users remember page names is a problem in general but in this case it is more to prevent people from finding the pages except if I explicitly tell them.

Answer (score 0):

One more nitpick: The "standard" way of doing this is through the `href` property of `window.location`:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
```

If you want to keep the current location out of the browser's history, use `replace()`:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/");
```